# How do I approach syncing a directory of files between clients?

Tags: synchronization

I'm building an application that works with a directory of files on the user's computer. I'm planning to implement a separate package that acts as a sync server. The client can register itself with the server and push files to it, and other clients (mobile app, etc) are able to register with the server as well to download the files from the server. This will function similar to how I'm reading Logseq and Obsidian implement their "Sync" features.

I have a few specific questions: when a file is modified, the client is expected to dispatch a request to the sync server that updates the file on the remote side. The file is encrypted before it leaves the client, and only unencrypted on another client when it is accessed again. The server is zero knowledge. So, what is the common strategy for doing this? is it common practice to encrypt and transmit the entire file with each change, or is it more common to implement a strategy which only transmits the actual changes to the file? If that is the case, how feasible is this as a solo developer?

Thanks for your time!